# Re-Usable AsynTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The app I am working has many url's where it posts the data. So instead of writting the async task again and again, I want to use a single async task to handle multiple URL.

Is it possible? If yes then how?
Please help me through it. Thank You.

Comment: create a function using AsyncTask

Comment: You can call the same AsyncTask as much as you want to.

Comment: but what about the parameters? they will keep on changing with every url...

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if it is a correct practice...but it can be done like this

```
String url = {.......};

for (int i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
AsyncTaskPost post = new AsyncTaskPost(url[i]);
post.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use volley library for dealing with urls. Its much better and bug free.

Comment: theY are using only single URL where as i want multiple UrL.

Comment: you can create a function to call the url in which you can pass the url and parameters for that. and can call a perticular function on completing loading from server.

Comment: can you just send me a sample if possible? using two url?

Comment: This should be a comment. And it would not even be a good one.